# Dynamically settings contents of iframe and resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following iframe

```
<iframe id="template-preview" src="about:blank" sandbox="allow-same-origin"  frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0"></iframe>
```

and I set the iframe contents using the below javascript+jquery

```
$('#template-preview').contents().find("html").html(code);
```

if I query the iframe's scroll height using

```
document.getElementById("template-preview").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight
```

or via

```
$('#template-preview').contents().height();
```

I get a null reference error, but if I change how I write to the iframe using the code below, finding and setting the iframe height based on the contents works.

```
    var myIframe = document.getElementById("template-preview")
    var iframeDoc = myIframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframeDoc.open();
    iframeDoc.write(code); 
    iframeDoc.close();
```

The question is why?